# How to avoid needless repetition?

Tags: writing-style, repetition

In German, repetition is frowned upon. For example:

Instead of the disfavored repetitions

> Der Professor betreut die Studenten bei der Ausarbeitung der Bachelorarbeiten und Masterarbeiten.
>
> Der Versand ist zuständig für den Wareneingang und Warenausgang.

it is recommended to shorten to

> Der Professor betreut die Studenten bei der Ausarbeitung der Bachelor- und Masterarbeiten.
>
> Der Versand ist zuständig für den Warenein- und -ausgang.

I know that repetition in English is allowed but is it possible to shorten sentences in English the same way as in German, too? Are there any official rules on how to remove repetition if I want to?

How do I avoid the multiple use of the same word in sentence like that:

> The professor supervises the students working on their Bachelor Thesis and Master Thesis
>
> The shipping department is in charge of receiving goods and outgoing goods

Comment: "... is frowned upon": in the sense of writing style? There is nothing ungrammatical about the redundancy in the given example. Sometimes it may be unavoidable or even necessary, though most of the time the sentence can be rephrased. And to call it redundancy even though in German, the repetition is only of a part of a compound form!

Comment: Is the question 'Should I avoid', or 'How to avoid'?

Comment: It's more about *May I and if yes, how to?*. ...  Of course it is grammatical correct in German, did I said something else? But as long as the understanding doesn't worsen it is a often used way of avoiding this repetition.

Comment: Why did you have a pleonasm in the title? In English it sounds bad. Do you do that in titles in German?

Comment: @Mitch Maybe redundant isn't the correct word. Does superfluous, dispensable or unnecessary make more sense? I just wanted to emphasize that the repetition is needless.

Comment: Your title uses multiple words redundantly. In fact it is a phrase commonly used in jokes about needlessly repetitive usage (you use it in your text so it seems you're not trying to make a joke). But if your title had been the less comedic 'How to avoid __needless__ repetition?', I think it would be obvious that the answer would be 'Don't do it then'.

Comment: Also, to @kris's question, it's still not clear (because you didn't modify your question) if you want to know if it is structurally -possible- (allowed at all) to remove the redundancy, if it is stylistically -encouraged-, or if you want to know -how- to remove it.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that the style in English is to not remove redundancy?

Comment: @Mitch I didn't know that. No, I'm not trying do make a joke. Not at all. I will improve the title.

Comment: I am still not sure what the question is here. You avoid repeating the word *thesis* by not repeating the word *thesis*, and you avoid repeating the word *goods* by not repeating the word *goods*. And that's what every single answer so far boils down to. Which is kind of pointless, innit.

Comment: @RegDwightѬſ道 Did I said that the answers aren't good? They already gave me the answer I am looking for and I will accept one as soon as I am sure which one is the best. I just try to improve the question since the comments of Mitch made clear to me, what the problem with *redundant* is. Why is the question still unclear? The (very short) answer in German would be "replace the redundant word with a hyphen". I didn't know *if it is possible in English, too* and if so *how*. But this is given in the question, isn't it?

Comment: Now that that's all cleared up, the answer is: Yes, stylistically, parallel repetition is frowned upon, just like in German. If the repetition that you are trying to remove is a stand alone word, just don't use it. If it is part of a longer word, like in German, then do just like German and use a hyphen. But that case is not as common as in German because English doesn't have the prolific word-joining features that German does.

Comment: @Mitch Perfect. If it isn't too much effort to you add that comment to your answer. Then let's hope that the question gets enough votes for reopening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redundancy is also frowned upon in English. Sometimes a little repetition is allowed for clarity. But usually repetition in exactly parallel constructions is considered bad form.

For your second example the better way to write it, without the needless repetition, is:

> The shipping department is in charge of receiving and outgoing goods.

There is a culture in expository writing (that is a style guide but not a rule) that says you should not repeat vocabulary items, that you should use synonyms. This guide tends not to work so well on technical writing (where exact meaning is required).

Comment: Do you mean something like: *He was very effusive in his praise. He gushily eulogized him as a hero.*

Comment: I'm not sure I see a repetition there. Was there an original that you had in mind that does have a redundancy? (Do you see how I did it in those two sentences? repetition and redundancy are near synonyms; I could have used either twice, but stylistically it sounds better using the two different ones. Did you think 'effusive' and 'gushily' are synonyms? 'gushily' is not really a good sounding word; 'gushingly' is probably an actual word. Aside from the grating semantic discordance of a 'gushing eulogy' (the guy's dead, no need to be so festive about it), correct, you wouldn't use 'effusively'.

Comment: Ok, I get it. This examples helped me. Is *gushy* excessively effusive, isn't it? If so, I can use it alternatively. I just didn't know that eulogy implies that the person is dead. I thought this means *could be dead*.

Comment: 'Gushy' is in the same area as 'effusive' but has connotations of ...it's in a more informal register, and that can make it different enough (but also possibly not usable in this context). As to implication of death, I've always taken a eulogy to be associated with death, and whether 'is' or 'could be', it is inclined towards the solemn rather than festive.

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem with repetition in English if it makes the meaning clear. There are several possibilities. Here are just two:

> The professor supervises not only those students working on their
>   Bachelor theses but those working on their Master theses as well.
>
> The professor supervises students working on their Bachelor and Master
>   theses.

Comment: Yeah, the first example you gave sounds terrible to me. I know that this is possible but I would never, never phrase it like that. I prefer the succinct sentences. :)

Comment: Well this is just playing with words Barrie and you have missed the example with"... both Bachelor and Master theses.","not only their Bachelor but their Master theses too" and ect.